# java junit and the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm really confused. I have a project "PROJ" and test project "PROJ.TEST"

PROJ is using classes from external.jar
In PROJ.TEST I write a test that is testing class from PROJ but this class is using class from external.jar.

And here is the problem. I get an error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

I have searched all the Internet to find the answer but couldn't find it. Even this great post http://blog.js-development.com/2010/06/android-instrumentation-test.html doesn't help me. 
I tried many combinations with Java Build Path and nothing :(

Regards

Comment: Can you post the classpath for both PROJ and PROJ.TEST? Are you using an IDE like Eclipse? Can you run the code from PROJ without the same error?

Comment: Sure, 1 PROJ have lib\ormlite-android-4.30.jar, lib\ormlite-core-4.30.jar. PROJ.TEST PROJ\lib\ormlite-android-4.30.jar, PROJ\lib\ormlite-core-4.30.jar. 2. Yes, Im using Eclipse. 3. Yes, I can run the code without ANY error, all PROJ works fine

Comment: What happens if you do a clean build of both projects? can you post your junit test and the code it's testing?

Comment: hmm what is clean build? without path build to the external jars? If yes then PROJ compiles, but PROJ.TEST not. The message occure that it must have a lib. Sure, the code is here http://paste.org/41195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post [Android Testing: External libraries](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html) probably contains the answer to your question and a step-by-step example.

Comment: thx for this link, in this note I've found hint. The main reason why it didn't work in my project was what I didn't delete references in PROJ.TEST to external jar. You safe my day :)